# is $f^2 (x) = f(f(x))$ a correct thing

Tags: functions, notation

The additional maths IGCSE states that
$f^2(x) = f(f(x))$

Yet almost every other source found online states that
$f^2(x) = f(x)\cdot f(x)$

Comment: It depends on the source and the convention used. There's no standard for this (cf. the trigonometric powers, like $\sin^2(x)$.

Comment: Sometimes it is denoted $f^{(2)}$ but even that can be confused with derivative notation

Comment: $f^n=\underbrace{f\circ \cdots\circ f}_{n\text{ times}}$ is definitely a notation and in the context of linear maps it's the undisputed standard. However, due to $f^n(x)=(f(x))^n$ being common too, especially for trigonometric functions, it's good to specify it.

Comment: Might be great to include the IGCSE content in the Post. "every other source found online" Might be useful to include the sources too. It is a Definition / Convention / Notation. Nothing right or wrong, when it is consistent.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine to define

$$f^n=\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f}_{\textstyle n\text{ times}}$$
and it's common notation when investigating (discrete) dynamical systems, for example, where one is analysing iterates of a function.

As always, make sure what notation you are using in the appendix, so readers can look up what you mean.

Most common form of it is the notation $f^{-1}$ for the inverse of $f$ (provided it exists), and I never came across a place that uses $f^{-1}(x) = 1/f(x)$.